# Android ContentResolver.query and Custom Columns

Tags: android, android-contentresolver

I want to make an Android App that includes a list of audio files with extra info from each file's ID3 tag.

I currently use [`ContentResolver.query`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentResolver.html#query%28android.net.Uri,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%29) to get the audio files. The ID3 data I want is not part of the common, queryable information, so once I get the filename I'll need to extract it myself.

My question is how to add that extra information to the cursor? I understand that I can't change the cursor structure. Can I add more columns in advance and fill the data later? Do I have to clone all the data to a new data structure of my own?

Itai.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your are reading audio file information from the built-in media database. In that case there is no way you can add this information to the cursor.

But you can get the extra information in your cursor-reading loop and put it and the information from the cursor into an object that will contain both.

If you are looking to use this with a `CursorAdapter` to fill a list view, there is no good way to put this information together.

Some possibilities:

1. Read the ID3 tag info when you bind the view in your adapter - this means you will be doing extra processing in the UI thread which may slow your app down.
2. Copy the information from the your cursor to your own database along with the ID3 tag information and read it from there the next time around - this means you will have repeating information of a potentially large size.

Comment: Yeah, I was afraid it'll get to that... guess I need to find out how to do this asynchronously now. Regarding the storage, I'll probably end up using my own DB with filenames and extra data, and somehow sync it with the global Android DB.

Comment: You could also use data from both sources. You could continue using your `CursorAdapter` and display data from it, and get the data from the ID3 tag in a background thread, and display it when it's available. You can look into `AsyncTask` for that, or into using a thread pool (check out the `Executors` class). This way you will eliminate the need to cache and sync, and your only problem would be implementing the background thread.

Comment: But since I can't add placeholders to the current cursor, I'll have to copy the data into another list, won't I?

Comment: Normally in a cursor adapter you would override the `bindView()` method. In the `bindView()` method you create and fill a view for a single row in the list view. But the information you put into this view can come from somewhere else as well. Here is a link to a simple tutorial about cursor adapter: http://chetanandroidarora.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/customcursoradapter/